# Full second quantization description of the polarizing beam splitter

Tags: quantum-optics, second-quantization

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411560/creating-an-operator-for-a-polarizing-beam-splitter?rq=1) in the attempt to construct an operator that describes PBS as it acts on single-photon states in the modes of a system. The answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20774/quantum-optics-of-a-polarizing-beam-splitter) question aims at the direction I'm considering but does not describe the full four modes one would need for each of the two sides of a PBS.

It appears there is no such description in the literature which is surprising for such an ubiquitous element for quantum optical experiments.

So does there exist such a description or is there a reason a PBS is significantly more difficult to describe in the language of creation- and annihilation operators of modes than an ordinary beam splitter?